# RIGHT Function in UPDATE Statement w/ Integer Field

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am attempting to run a simple `UPDATE` script on an `integer` field, whereby the trailing 2 numbers are "kept", and the leading numbers are removed.  For example, "0440" would be updated as "40."  I can get the desired data in a `SELECT` statement, such as

```
SELECT RIGHT(field_name::varchar, 2) 
FROM table_name;
```

However, I run into an error when I try to use this same functionality in an `UPDATE` script, such as:

```
UPDATE schema_name.table_name 
SET field_name = RIGHT(field_name::varchar, 2);
```

The error I receive reads:

> column . . . is of type integer but expression is of type text . . .
>   HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression

Comment: For clarification, is `field_name` an `int` or `varchar` column in your table?

Comment: @ChrisJ: Title and error msg say `integer`. (Though the question text is a bit misleading.)

Comment: The issue seems too obvious, so I thought it was worth clarifying 

Answer (score 0):

You're casting the integer to varchar but you're not casting the result back to integer.

```
UPDATE schema_name.table_name 
SET field_name = RIGHT(field_name::TEXT, 2)::INTEGER;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite straight forward - `right` returns textual data, which you cannot assign to an integer column. You could, however, explicitly cast it back:

```
UPDATE schema_name.table_name 
SET    field_name = RIGHT(field_name::varchar, 2)::int;
```

Answer (score 0):

`1` is a *digit* (or a number - or a string), '123' is a *number* (or a string).

Your example `0440` does not make sense for an `integer` value, since leading (insignificant) `0` are not stored.

Strictly speaking data type `integer` is no good to store the "trailing 2 numbers" - meaning *digits* - since `00` and `0` both result in the same integer value `0`. But I don't think that's what you meant.

For operating on the numeric value, don't use string functions (which requires casting back and forth. The [modulo operator **`%`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html#functions-math-op-table) does what you need, exactly: `field_name%100`. So:

```
UPDATE schema_name.table_name 
SET    field_name = field_name%100
WHERE  field_name > 99;  -- to avoid empty updates
```